# Pass a pointer to a static method

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

Why does the compiler treat `&Foo::foo` as `void (*)()`. I am expecting it to be treated as `void(Foo::*)()` instead since it's a member of `Foo`.

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        static void foo ( void ){}
};

void foo ( void(Foo::*)(void) ){}

int main()
{   
    foo(&Foo::foo);  // error: cannot convert ‘void (*)()’ to ‘void (Foo::*)()’
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No the other variant needs a plain function member, because the `this` pointer is implicitely passed to this function (That's what the `Foo::*` is for).

Comment: @g-makulik I am sorry, I can not get your point. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: chris' answer points it out very clearly, `void(Foo::*)()` is for (non static members only). Also note that `->*` for dereferencing a member function pointer forms an operator of its own, which can't be overridden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared the function foo as **static**.

It is therefore not a member function of a Foo instance.

This code works:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    static void foo ( void ){}
    void foo2() {}
};

void foo ( void(*)(void) ){}
void fooMember ( void(Foo::*)(void) ){}

int main()
{   
    foo(&Foo::foo);
    fooMember(&Foo::foo2); 
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I updated the description and added a piece of code.

Comment: That's rather misleading - it's still a (static) member. More accurately, a pointer-to-member is only used for non-static members, which are only accessible via an object.

Comment: Consider changing `It is therefore no member function of Foo.` to `It is therefore not a member function of a Foo instance` because it is a member of Foo class.

Comment: I find the C++ syntax for delegates rather confusing. What is the accessable name of the passed function? `void(*)(void)` is only the type right...?